# Хостинг для django проекта

Tags: python, django, хостинг

изучаю django, сформировал сайт на локальном компьютере. Решил выложить его на хостинг и столкнулся с проблемой что ни где нет нормальной информации о том как правильно выложить сайт на хостинг. Выбрал хостинг jino закачал файлы на хостинг создал виртуальное окружение установил django по инструкции от jino создал файлы .htaccess и wsgi файлы, запускаю сайт и получаю 500 ошибку, а в логах вижу

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

почему то не видит джанго, по ssh подключаюсь ввожу команды import django всё работает.
Кто работал в jino подскажите пожалуйста как выложить сайт, а то техподдержка игнорит уже 3 день.

Comment: а по инструкции на хостинге пробовали пустой проект создавать и получать на выходе стартовую страницу?

Comment: да пробывал тоже не получается, выпадает та же ошибка

Comment: а вообще не понятно почему так виртуальное окружение создается с помощью команды virtualenv-3.6 env 
В python 3 создается оно так python3 -m venv myvenv

Answer (score 0):

Итог такой что интерпритатор должен быть той же версии что и виртуальное окружение, а у меня виртальное окружение было virtualenv-3.6, а python 3.7